# Operate with date timezone

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have `Date` on client side (user choose it in date picker) and I want to send it to server and use UTC value for future calculations.
For example, user chooses `Tue Oct 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (E. Europe Daylight Time)`, I send milliseconds to server using `date.getTime()`. On server I use method:

```
public static DateTime GetDateByMilliseconds(long milliseconds)
{
    var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    return date.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);
}
```

And get `Oct 03, 2011 09:00:00 PM`. But I want to operate with value `Oct 04 2011 00:00:00`.
What should I do? Reset date timezone on client side? Add offset on server? Anything else?

Comment: They are the same values. You say you want to use UTC, `Oct 03, 2011 09:00:00 PM` *is* the UTC value of `Tue Oct 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0300`. I don't understand the question...

Comment: Javascript will give you UTC time, so later on you will have to add/subtract the offset from the value to get your DateTime object

Comment: I am not 100% clear on what exactly it is you are asking...however, what I can be clear with you on is do your calculations in UTC, not local and then convert it back to local time for display purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)
```

This will "remove" the offset for the user timezone.